# Calculating Percentile in MDX

Tags: mdx, iccube

Does icCube provide any function that can be used for creating calculated members with aggregated percentile, like Median or 95th percentile?

Answer (score 1):

For the [median](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Median.php) there is an MDX function available. Percentile is not yet directly supported, looks as a good idea to add, but we can user the [Vector MDX+ function](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Vector.php) applying the [percentile object function](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_types/vector.php).

```
Vector( [Set] , [Value], EXCLUDEEMPTY )->percentile(50)   // for the median
```

same as

```
Median( [Set] , [Value] )
```

---

If you're looking to do this directly from a measure (fact level). There is a list of [aggregation methods](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/facts_aggregation.php) that return a Vector. Let's say we've defined a measure [P&L Vector] with the aggregation method Vector. Then for the median would be :

```
[P&L Vector]->percentile(50)
```

---

From the coming 6.2 version there will be an MDX function to support Percentile:

```
 Percentile( [Set], [Value] , 95 )
```